# What flaps are used for, if the aircraft has already landed?

Tags: lift, flaps, boeing-747

When watching the below clip in the final approach sequence we can clearly hear setting flabs to 1, 2 and then to maximum.

At [12:05](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KK5KTQGuXSQ&t=720s) into the clip, when fully landed plane is rolling through airport, FO says that flaps are set to 1. As I understand, they were changed from "max" to "1" a moment ago.

What is the reason of moving the flaps when plane is rolling after landing? Does it affect anything?

I am a total theoretical noob to the flying, but I was always more than sure that flaps are used to modify the lifting force of the wings (that's why they're set to "max" during final approach, to extend wings and its lift to maximum).

So, what am I missing?

Comment: They aren't used on the ground, which is why they are retracted after landing.

Comment: When I worked with LH in KUL, the A340-600 would block in with the LE slats and flaps deployed (flaps at 1st setting). I was told this was to improve cooling of the flap/slat mechanism.

Comment: @MaxR Cooling issues (31C / 86F in example clip) as outlined above in the comment (Anvil) and in the linked duplicate answer seems proving that you are wrong. **There is** purpose and upside of having slats extended during post-landing taxi.

Comment: A bit of ancient history:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/is-it-considered-good-or-bad-practice-to-raise-the-flaps-right-after-touchdown